# Suppose I start a multi-process then within that multi-process I start a thread and kill the multi-process. What happens to my thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a unique situation where I open forms using the PyQt5 and multiprocessing library.

Each of these forms can import and run test scripts used to test some hardware components. I use multiprocessing so the print statements for the test are re-routed to a window in the UI while the test is running. (re-routed using sys.stdout = {my ui text display} ). Within that multi-process, I start a thread to run the test so the UI doesn't lock up and show not responding.

What will happen to my thread if I close the form (ending my multi-process) but never finish my thread?

The thread is a child of the multi-process, but I'm not sure if the thread gets interrupted just because it's parent is trying to close.
There doesn't seem to be any obvious affect from it, but I assume it is a memory leak or the thread will just crash at some point in the background when it tries to return data to my multi-process.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759831/python-kill-all-child-processes-when-main-process-is-killed may be what you ask about

Comment: Ah yes I should use Daemon flag to ensure it closes.

Answer (score 2):

When you kill a process everything related to it is killed too, since it's the OS that handles the processes, you don't need to worry about your thread being "forever alive".

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373439/does-a-thread-terminate-automatically-if-its-main-process-is-forcefully-ended#:~:text=When%20you%20kill%20process%2C%20everything,The%20system%20just%20kills%20everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373439/does-a-thread-terminate-automatically-if-its-main-process-is-forcefully-ended#:%7E:text=When%20you%20kill%20process%2C%20everything,The%20system%20just%20kills%20everything).